# Too many parentheses to format a percentage in SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

This query seems to have way too many parentheses.

```
SELECT
CAST(ISNULL(ROUND(CAST((SUM(product1) + SUM(product2)) AS FLOAT) / CAST(salescalls.visits AS FLOAT) * 100, 2), 0) AS VARCHAR) + '%' AS avrg
FROM sales, salescalls
WHERE sales.salescallId = salescalls.id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something you can do about

```
CAST((SUM(product1) + SUM(product2)) AS FLOAT) / CAST(salescalls.visits AS FLOAT) * 100
```

To perform floating-point division rather than integer division, either the dividend or the divisor needs to be a float.  You don't need make both of operands floats.  Furthermore, you can make a the dividend a float by using floating-point multiplication.  That means that you don't need to cast anything to a float.  That simplifies it to

```
100.0 * (SUM(product1) + SUM(product2)) / salescalls.visits
```

Next, you can rewrite the sums as one aggregate by adding the two columns in each row before summing the rows:

```
100.0 * SUM(product1 + product2) / salescalls.visits
```

I don't think that there's not much that can be done about `ROUND()`, `ISNULL()`, and `CAST(… AS VARCHAR)`, though.  Consider doing that formatting in your application-layer code instead of SQL.

---

You've written the query using an old-style join.  It would be better to write it using a `JOIN` keyword:

```
SELECT CAST(
           ISNULL(
               ROUND(
                   100.0 * SUM(product1 + product2) / salescalls.visits,
                   2
               ),
               0
           ) AS VARCHAR
       ) + '%' AS avrg
    FROM sales INNER JOIN salescalls ON sales.salescallId = salescalls.id
```

Comment: I agree with the old-style join being ugly.  That's how the queries I'm working with are written so I just stick with it.